# Easeljs hexagon grid with background for each tile

Tags: background, grid, textures, easeljs, tile

I'd like to create **an hexagonal grid** with Easeljs, but with a specific background texture **for each tile**, and some tiles may have the same background image (in this example I've put only one background image for starters).

I've done the hexagonal grid, however the background image filling that I've used is reapeating itself on all the canvas whereas I would like that each tile of the grid has its own background image, so that the background doesn't have such an offset like currently :

[Résultat](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Shbf2.png)

Here's my code, I'm using beginBitmapFill:

```
$().ready(function() {
        var stage, dist, rayon, texture, hexagons = [], hexagon;
        stage = new createjs.Stage("canvas");
        stage.enableMouseOver();
        dist = 60;

        var manifest = [
            {src: "penguin3.png", id: "penguin3"}
        ];

        var loader = new createjs.LoadQueue(false);
        loader.addEventListener("complete", function() {
            for (var y=0; y < 8; y++) {
                for (var x=-Math.floor(y/2); x < -Math.floor(y/2)+8; x++) {
                    hexagon = new Hexagon(x, y, dist, loader.getResult('penguin3'), stage);
                    hexagons.push(hexagon);
                    stage.addChild(hexagon);
                }
            }

            stage.hexagonsNumber = hexagons.length;
            stage.update();
        });
        loader.loadManifest(manifest, true, "/images/");
});

function Hexagon(x, y, dist, texture, stage)
{
    createjs.Shape.call(this);
    this.coordsX = x;
    this.coordsY = y;
    this.dist = dist;
    this.texture = texture;
    this.stage = stage;

    this.drawShape();
}

Hexagon.prototype = new createjs.Shape();
Hexagon.prototype.constructor = Hexagon;

Hexagon.prototype.getShapeCoordinates = function()
{
    return {
        x: 50 + this.dist * (this.coordsX + this.coordsY / 2),
        y: 50 + Math.sqrt(3) * this.dist * this.coordsY / 2 ,
        radius: this.dist / Math.sqrt(3)
    };
};

Hexagon.prototype.drawShape = function()
{
    var shapeCoordinates = this.getShapeCoordinates();

    this.graphics
        .beginBitmapFill(this.texture, 'no-repeat')
        .beginStroke(createjs.Graphics.getRGB(0,0,0))
        .drawPolyStar(shapeCoordinates.x, shapeCoordinates.y, shapeCoordinates.radius, 6, 0, 30)
        .endFill();
};
```

I'm new to Easeljs to I'm maybe doing something wrong... thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is happening because you are changing the coordinates where you draw the hexagon, instead of changing the hexagon's actual x and y position. This means that the origin of the bitmap fill is not changed.

Here is a quick port of your code:
http://jsfiddle.net/lannymcnie/ygfrs0pn/

I modified the draw routine to move the actual Shape instance's x and y, and set the graphics draw routine to `[0,0]`.
http://jsfiddle.net/lannymcnie/ygfrs0pn/1/

```
 var shapeCoordinates = this.getShapeCoordinates();
 this.x = shapeCoordinates.x;
 this.y = shapeCoordinates.y;

 this.graphics
        .beginBitmapFill(this.texture, 'no-repeat')
        .beginStroke(createjs.Graphics.getRGB(0,0,0))
        .drawPolyStar(0,0, shapeCoordinates.radius, 6, 0, 30)
        .endFill();
```

This makes each tile look the same, which is (I think) what you had in mind.

Comment: Ah yes this makes much more sense to move the hexagon than to draw from the (0,0) coordinates, you're right!

Thanks a lot, that solves my problem :)